# BuffedWriter save of large amounts of BLE data causes GKI error

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bufferedwriter

I have an Android app from which I receive BLE data (every 62ms via notifications). The app can save data via a BufferedWriter to a file. Upon ending the save of large amounts of data, I see an error such as this: GKI_exception out of buffers  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65455 (except my code is not scanning but receiving notifications). I don't see this error for 100s of kB saves, but I see it on 1-2MB saves in logcat, and on >5-6MB saves I need to power cycle the Nexus 7 (the app and BLE become totally unresponsive). I call close() on the BufferedWriter at the end of the save. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely thread related. You need to make sure that the "save" operation (which is writing file data to disk...an operation that takes a long time) is not happening in the same thread context that could block your BLE notifications or a related callback. If you block a thread that keeps a BLE callback method from returning, you will see the Bluetooth stack get starved, which is what that callback usually means.

Simplest thing is to always make sure you write file data in a new background thread (like an `AsyncTask`, `Thread`, or `IntentService` for instance), ensuring that regardless of what thread you were coming from, the long write to flash memory won't block the current context.

Comment: Hi Dave, many thanks for your great Android BLE tutorial; that's the basis for my code! Yes, the issue is likely thread related. I open and close the BufferedWriter in the main thread, but call its write() in each  onCharacteristicRead() callback. I should move the calls to write() in the handler (called via sendMessage()). Do you think that's the issue and a sufficient solution, or still  need to make another AsyncTask?

Comment: If you are receiving notifications, wouldn't the value come in onCharacteristicChanged()? Either way, I would recommend exactly that. If lots of writes stack up, or the write is sufficiently large, you are blocking the callback thread(s) for too long. You could pipe them back to the main thread via the Handler, but then you may cause them to block UI events instead. Since the writes are happening that frequently, possibly create a new HandlerThread that can process the file writer over using AsyncTask every time.

Comment: Sorry, I meant onCharacteristicChanged() for notifications. I'll try your solution.

Comment: It seems to work if I use AsyncTask, but not if I make a Thread. I'll post a new question regarding that.

Comment: Hi Dave, would you please be able to address my related question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654576/android-thread-vs-asynctask-called-from-ble-oncharacteristicchanged?